# How to enable proxies correctly with scrapy-proxies and scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am using [scrapy-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) and [scrapy-fake-useragent](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent#:%7E:text=Random%20User%2DAgent%20middleware%20for,a%20backup%2C%20powered%20by%20Faker) in my project. However, the requests are routing through my public IP address, not the proxies.

The settings.py file

```
BOT_NAME = 'scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'

REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 5
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 30

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True 

RETRY_TIMES = 10
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 200,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 201,
}

PROXY_LIST = 'proxies.txt'
PROXY_MODE = 0

FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS = [
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider', 
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider',  
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider',
]

USER_AGENT ='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
RANDOM_UA_PER_PROXY = True

DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD = "TLSv1.2"

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scraper.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline': 600
}
```

I have tried changing the priorities in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES but I was unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that no need to set `USER_AGENT` because you've set `RANDOM_UA_PER_PROXY = True` already, I'm not sure which one's priority is higher.